# How to show Android's virtual-keyboard when focus an input in TWebBrowser?

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe5, twebbrowser, android-virtual-keyboard

I created a simple application in Delphi-XE5 for Android. It only has an `TWebBrowser` object that goes straight to a certain website when the application runs. But when I focus/touch on any of the webform's inputs nothing happens. The cursor goes to the input but the virtual keyboard does not show up.

Do I have to put some code on an `Event` or... is it some Delphi's bug?

Comment: Maybe related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3460915/webview-textarea-doesnt-pop-up-the-keyboard

Comment: @GabrielF thanks but we are talking about Delphi, not Java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is a bug in Delphi TWebBrowser. Or they want us to believe that it is as designed so you only use web browser for viewing web pages with no interaction. However there is a workaround for it

```
procedure TFormBrowserAdd.ButtonNavigateClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WebBrowser.CanFocus := True;
  WebBrowser.Navigate(EditUrl.Text);
  WebBrowser.SetFocus;
end;
```

You can read the whole article [here](http://www.fmxexpress.com/virtual-keyboard-with-twebbrowser-on-android-in-delphi-xe5-firemonkey/). Also check this [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20898915/firemonkey-twebbrowser-input-alternative) entry. There is also a QC report that is marked resolved which might indicate that the fix will be shipped in XE6 or later.